# use two different authentication backends for different types of users

Tags: django, authentication, backend

My django application has two kind of users.

1. Employer. Uses the default model based authentication backend.
2. Candidate. Must use the token based authentication backend.

I have the backend in place for employers but how can I use the second token based backend for the candidate related part of the application?

Comment: Yes it is. I didn't quite understood the method of chaining auth backends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django provides an `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting which should do what you require.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Ours looks like this ....

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',  # fb backend par social_auth
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',  # twitter backend par social_auth
    'backends.EmailAuthBackend',
    'backends.APIAuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

In out case, the `backends.APIAuthBackend` is where we check the supplied user auth token. You simply need to write your authentication code in the `def authenticate` method of that class which returns a user if the token exists.

The django docs provides more info.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend